# How to organize multi-lib project?

Tags: c++, git, qt, project

I have to maintain a project with following structure (every list item is separate git repository):

1. gui
2. gui lib №1...N
3. backend
4. backend lib №1...N

Right now i give setup instructions to my new coworkers as README.md inside gui repo:

```
git clone gui
git clone gui lib №1...N
git clone backend
git clone backend lib №1...N
pushd backend lib №1...N
qmake && make
popd
pushd backend
qmake && make
popd
pushd gui lib №1...N
qmake && make
popd
```

but it feels really lame to do so.
Can you guys give me any hint on how to do this right way?
Thank you!

Comment: Add git submodules to your project repository.

Comment: @273K So i should make wrapper git repo with submodules and define all build logick i need inside wrapper .pro file?